# WPF Binding issue

Tags: binding

I am having a weird issue.

I am trying to bind to an image object. I can bind the RenderTransform perfectly. But the OpacityProperty will not bind correctly. I don't get errors but opacity will not update or change while the TranslationTransform will. I have no idea why:

```
Dim alpha As New Double
alpha = 0

Dim vImage As Image = CreatevImageControl()
Dim translation As New TranslateTransform(0, 0)

myGrid.Children.Add(vImage)
Dim binding1 As New Binding()
binding1.Source = translation
vImage.SetBinding(Image.RenderTransformProperty, binding1)

Dim binding2 As New Binding()
binding2.Source = alpha
vImage.SetBinding(Image.OpacityProperty, binding2)

alpha = 1
translation.X = -150
```

Answer (score 1):

How would your OpacityProperty know if alpha has changed?
Automatic updates with Binding relies on notification when a property changes. Either with a dependency property or a class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.

So in your case, alpha needs to be a dependency property or the property of some class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Your TranslateTransform will notify the binding about the update, since "X" is a dependency property of TranslateTransform. Thus, the binding can hook up a change event and update the binding target changes occur.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up putting an image object property within the class that defines the custom object I want to bind to. Ended up working well because all the props are there and everything is done runtime.